# Windows 10 UWP Application - Error whilst creating package

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone, windows-10-universal, windows-dev-center, appxmanifest

I currently have a windows phone 8.1 application in the store and have decided to upgrade it to windows 10 UWP. I've created a new version of the app from scratch using VS 2015 3 RC and used the options in the project menu to associate the app with one already on my account.

When I do this the appxmanifest file is updated with the wrong PublisherDisplayName - instead of my name it's coming up with **Microsoft account**. If I build the package with this name it all completes without error however if I change to to what is on my developer account then I get the following error

**The PublisherDisplayName element of the Properties element in the app manifest must have the value of the Publisher display name value from your developer account: Microsoft account**

I've tried logging out/in on my developer account, repairing VS, reinstalling VS etc. confirmed my developer account has the correct name but still the problem occurs.

Any suggestions right now would be most welcome!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was having the same issue, I believe it's because the Package.StoreAssociation.xml doesn't download/build correctly, and then if you change your publisher name in the Package.appmanifest then the two don't align.

To fix this, make sure that the

```
<PublisherDisplayName></PublisherDisplayName>
```

element in the Package.StoreAssociation.xml file (usually found in the root of your project) is set to the same as the

> Dev centre -> Account Settings -> Public info -> Publisher display name

which is also set to the same as your "publisher display name" in your

> package.appmanifest -> Packaging tab.

This should resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for this Hassan. I actually went down the route of creating a VM to build the app which did the job for me. Looking at history on the files I can confirm that what you have said is correct and the two parameters do not match in the files so I've marked your response as the answer.

Comment: I have a script which automatically build different version of the app. Thank you for your answer! All I need to know that I also need to maintain separate versions of `Package.StoreAssociation.xml` file for different versions of the app. After I fixed it, all works fine!!!

Comment: After setting that I'm still getting the error. It says: "The PublisherDisplayName element of the Properties element in the app manifest must have the value of the Publisher display name value from your developer account: .". Notice how my publisher name is perceived as blank from the store. However it doesn't appear as such in the developer center.